# how to delete a file from a subfolder within a folder using php

Tags: php

I have to delete a file from the database and also to delete the file from the folder which is stored in server as files(folder)/newsletter(subfolder)/file1 using php.Iam using following code,the file is deleting from the database,but its not deleting from the folder,..plz help,thanks in advance.

my code is..

```
<?php

$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);

include 'db/connection.php';

$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from newsletters where id=$id");
$results = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if ($results["file"] != "") {

    $image = $results["file"];

    unlink('../files/newsletter/' . $image);
}

$sql = "delete from newsletters where id=$id";

$result = @mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Some errors occured.'));
}

?>
```

Comment: y r u using the .. notation? what is the path of the page/file containing this code?

Comment: just read out about exec() command on php manaul.

Comment: FYI, `mysql` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of this path "../files/newsletter/" should mention correct path and if your server is ubuntu based then change permissions to **files** ,**newsletter** folders.

Comment: Iam using 1and1 server

Comment: the server os is linux or windows?